# Actionscript Workers don't work on Mac OSX (Flash Player 11.7)

Tags: macos, actionscript-3, air

Mac OSX version 10.8.4
Adobe Air SDK 3.7
Flash Player 11.7 debug version for Mac OSX

I've also tried Adobe Air SDK 3.8 beta, but the result is the same.

My code is very simple.

main:

```
package sandbox
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.system.Worker;
    import flash.system.WorkerDomain;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    public class TestWorkerMain extends Sprite
    {
        [Embed(source="../../workerswfs/sandbox/TestWorker.swf", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
        private static var Worker_ByteClass:Class;
        private var worker:Worker;

        public function TestWorkerMain()
        {
            var bytes:ByteArray = new Worker_ByteClass();
            worker = WorkerDomain.current.createWorker(bytes);
            worker.start();
            super();
        }
    }
}
```

worker:

```
package sandbox
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.utils.Timer;

    public class TestWorker extends Sprite
    {
        public function TestWorker()
        {
            super();
            var t:Timer = new Timer(1000);
            t.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,onTimer);
            t.start();
        }

        protected function onTimer(event:TimerEvent):void
        {
            trace("working ... ");
        }
    }
}
```

On Windows I can see my worker in Scout report, but on Mac there's no worker shown.

The worker functions fine, but I think it's synced with the main thread, which makes it meaningless to use a worker.

Does anyone have this problem on Mac OSX?

PS:I am not using chrome embedded Flash plugin, I am using Adobe one.

Answer (score 0):

GOT IT TO WORK! I've been trouble shooting on & off for 2 days. Even upgraded my iMac to Mountain Lion. Still didn't fix the problem. I was using Safari for my browser. Finally, I thought maybe that's the problem. So, I downloaded/installed latest Firefox. NOW IT WORKS! So, looks like I'm back to using Firefox for now... it's been a while. WTF!!! Glad I solved the prob tho!